# List all methods of a specified class in assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-assembly

I would like to have the Public methods listed from an external assembly. This works so far. My problem is that all methods from all classes are displayed. I have a listview element that gives me the namespace + class names.
E. g. DLL.Class1 / DLL.Class2

If I now click on DLL.Class1 in listview I want him to show me the methods (subs/functions) for this class in another listview.

Here's my current code:

```
  Private Sub CarbonFiberButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        CheckDll()
    End Sub
    Private Sub CheckDll()
        Try
            Dim loadedDll As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(txt_path.Text)

            Dim publicClasses = loadedDll.GetExportedTypes.Where(Function(p) p.IsClass And p.IsPublic)
            For Each classItem In publicClasses
                lv_classes.Items.Add(classItem.ToString)
            Next

        Catch e As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
            Debug.Print(e.Message)
    End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub lv_classes_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lv_classes.DoubleClick
        Dim currentClass As String = lv_classes.Items.Item(lv_classes.SelectedIndex).ToString
        MsgBox(lv_classes.Items.Item(lv_classes.SelectedIndex).ToString)
        lv_methods.Items.Clear()
        Try
            Dim loadedDll As Assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(txt_path.Text)

            Dim types As Type() = loadedDll.GetTypes()
            Dim arrl As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
            For Each cls As Type In types
                Dim methodName As MemberInfo() = cls.GetMethods()
                For Each method As MemberInfo In methodName
                    If method.ReflectedType.IsPublic Then arrl.Add(method.Name.ToString())
                Next
            Next
            For i As Integer = 0 To arrl.Count - 1
                lv_methods.Items.Add(arrl(i).ToString())
            Next
        Catch z As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(z.Message)
            Debug.Print(z.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

It would be very nice if someone give me a tip.
I am very new to work with assemblys!.

Comment: You're already looping through all types... Why not just check the type from within the loop?

Comment: Thats right. But the second listview shows me the methods of all classes from the assembly. i just want to list the methods from the clicked class.

For Each cls As Type In types.Where(classname = listview.item) something like this .... but i stuck here

Comment: Stuck on which part? getting the selected item, building the predicate, or getting the class name from the type? You already have a predicate in your code and already look at properties of the type, so I'm not sure where you're stuck unless you've just copied and pasted code and don't really understand what it's doing.

Comment: Read the API reference documentation. `method.ReflectedType.IsPublic` is completely wrong, as that tests if the class is public, not the method itself.

Comment: Ok i got it. The solution was :                 For Each method As MemberInfo In methodName
                    If method.ReflectedType.IsPublic And method.DeclaringType.FullName = currentClass Then arrl.Add(method.Name.ToString())
                Next